# Including external jars permanently in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, jar, desktop-application, netbeans-8

I'm building a Java Swing Application. This project requires a jar file called JCalender. I've added this to Libraries folder and  everything works fine on my computer in NetBeans. But when i open the same project in my friends NetBeans, it doesn't recognizes this library. I've to manually select the file placed inside the projects dist/lib folder. How to avoid this? please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when i open the same project in my friends NetBeans, it doesn't
>   recognizes this library. I've to manually select the file placed
>   inside the projects dist/lib folder. How to avoid this?

You can't *avoid* this because it's not a problem actually. To compile and run a project you need to have access to the external libraries involved in the development, so if you open your NetBeans project in a different computer than yours you will definitely need to resolve the reference to the external libraries. There's no way for the IDE to do it automatically as far as I know.

> Can't i give the relative path to the lib folder for that specific
>   library somewhere in project properties?

You could just give it a try. IMHO if the real goal is to share a project with other developers then I'd change the strategy. I'd create a Library (Tools -> Libraries) and tell my mates to create the very same library including the `JCalendar` JAR files in the library's classpath. I'd include this library in the project properties and finally I'd use a versioning tool like Git or SVN to share the project.

By doing this your mates still need a copy of the JAR file wrapped in a NetBeans Library, but the project properties won't point to a fixed/relative path looking for a JAR file but wil include a reference to a given Library. The Library itself will resolve the dependency to the JAR file. If you take a look to the `project.properties` file you'll see something like this:

```
javac.classpath=\
    ${file.reference.jcalendar-1.4.jar}
```

But if you as I've suggested then you'll see something like this:

```
javac.classpath=\
    ${libs.JCalendar.classpath}
```

Here `libs.JCalendar.classpath` will resolve the dependency so your mates can have the actual JAR file located in whatever folder they like and the project should compile just fine.

Another option is using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to manage the projects dependencies but honestly I'm not a Maven expert so I can't help you in this path.

Comment: can't i give the relative path to the lib folder for that specific library somewhere in project properties?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a "clean and build" and your jar will be in the dist folder. It will include the external jars

You can read more about it [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html)

Comment: Yes, it is there... But other netbeans don't recognise it automatically. I have to locate it every time i open the project elsewhere.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP is asking how to automatically resolve external libraries dependencies when they open the very same project in a different computer. Not how to include external libraries when build their project. There's a slight difference.

Comment: @dic19 you are right. Your answer should be accepted by OP

Comment: is that solved now @steven35 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to you are providing absolute path of jar file.
while choosing jar on write side of filechooser there is option of
Relative path and Absolute path there you should click on Absolute path.

Comment: Absolute path is by default selected. And relative path too doesn't solve the problem.. thanks for the advice mate!

Answer (score 0):

i am  new to java , but  anyway , i have faced the same problem and found a solution for my project

If you are in Netbeans , its would be very easy for you

Let you project name is **ABC** and all your dependent jar file is under the 
the folder **MyResourceCollection**

now we need to permanently import all jars under this folder ,

So from Netbeans ,

1. right click on your **project name**
2. go to **properties**
3. go to **library**
4. in the library page , check the **"libraries folder"** label
5. you can find a **browse** button at the right side of the label
6. click **browse** and select the **MyResourceCollection** folder
7. a new window will come , just press **Next-->Next--->Finish**

all is done , now check yourself by moving the folder into different location